# Should we delete older, on-hold, questions?

Tags: discussion, se-guidance

Is there any guidance from SE about our deleting older questions which we've put on hold?

We have a LOT of home/residential stuff that we put on hold. I'm just wondering if we should be cleaning up the questions that we put on hold. We don't want to be attracting more questions like them, and I don't think having them around is helping. Clearly, the home/residential askers are not seeing those on-hold Qs and thinking, "oh, I should ask my Q here."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, [Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) will delete zero-score (or lower) questions  [after 9 days of inactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/160519).

If the [Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) hasn't already deleted a home networking question, we absolutely should do so.